# selecting particular item in dropdownlist in angularjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I want to select particular item in dropdownlist with angularjs i used this code but it is not working

```
   <select class="form-control" ng-model="primaryObjectId" ng-change="getPrimaryObjectColumns()">
                <option value="{{object.id}}" ng-repeat="object in objectList">{{object.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

in controller.js

```
$scope.primaryObjectId = "3";
```

but is selecting first item in list i want to select 3rd item from list

Comment: is it displaying the list?

Comment: Use ``ng-options`` instead ``ng-repeat``

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) with [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

In many cases, ngRepeat can be used on  elements instead of ngOptions to achieve a similar result. However, ngOptions provides some benefits such as reducing memory and increasing speed by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance, as well as providing more flexibility in how the 's model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression.

```
 <select ng-options="items for items in objectList" ng-model="primaryObjectId"></select>
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/613/)

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/614/) to get items based on value of option item.

Set drop down item based on id. See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/615/)

Comment: thankyou but i want to select dropdown list based on id

Comment: not like this items have a property id,name in this name is displayed in dropdownlist i want to select perticular name based on item id